# Can 'a place' have 'a vibe'?

Tags: word-usage

> Members and White House aides say Trump appears to be more comfortable at **Bedminster**, which, according to one member who enjoys reciprocal privileges, **has a "totally different" vibe**.

As I understand, the **which** clause(..., *has a "totally different" vibe*) is modifying the word **Bedminster**, which is a place name. Virtually, it becomes: *Bedminster has a "totally different" vibe*. I am wondering if a place can have a vibe, because the dictionary definition of **vibe** is:

> Vibes are the good or bad atmosphere that you sense with a person or in a place.

So, it seems to me that only a **person** can have a vibe of something or someplace. For example, "*Sorry, Chris, but I have bad vibes about this guy*."

The [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/news/trumps-summer-dont-call-vacation-180040899--politics.html).

Comment: it says, right there in your definition, "in a place".

Comment: @Sam, I thought the definition says "*Vibes are the good or bad atmosphere that you sense with a person*" or "*Vibes are the good or bad atmosphere that you sense in a place*". But the point is the subject is still a person in either case. Did I just misinterpreted the definition?

Comment: A place has "a good or bad atmosphere". A place has "a good or bad vibe". The vibe applies to the place.

Comment: [*vibe*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vibe): "1. *countable noun* - Vibes are the good or bad atmosphere that you sense with a person or in a place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can say "this place has a good vibe" or "This person has a good vibe".

These mean "You feel a good atmosphere in this place".  So when you say "this place has a good vibe, there is an implied subject.

In the sentence that you quote, it is Trump and the unnamed "member" who feel a good atmosphere in Bedminster.